# Angular & Charts

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply charts in my demo Angular for the first time, I have done below example, but it doesn't show anything, HTML result is a blank page.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div class="el-overlay">

                <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
                chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
              </canvas>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as angular from 'angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'ea-starter',
    templateUrl: './starter.component.html'
})
export class StarterComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    title:string;
    subtitle:string;    
    constructor() {

            angular.module("angular2demo", ["chart.js"]).controller("DoughnutCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
                $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
            });         
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){

    }
}
```

Log result :

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.  core.es5.js:2925
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.  2.chunk.js:33857:5
[WDS] Warnings while compiling.  client:41
./~/raw-loader!./~/source-map-loader!./src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js
Cannot find SourceMap 'popper.min.js.map': Error: Can't resolve './popper.min.js.map' in '/Users/waelabdeen/Desktop/meitseticket/src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js'
 @ ./~/script-loader!./src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js 1:92-340
 @ multi script-loader!./src/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/sidebarmenu.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/custom.js script-loader!./src/assets/plugins/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js  client:106
[WDS] Disconnected!  client:45
```

Comment: You seem to be randomly mixing Angular and AngularJS, which is unlikely to lead to success. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: you are mixing angular and angular js

Comment: check this on how to use charts in angular [charts](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/charts)

Comment: i have updated the ticket with the log result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing angular and angularjs together, Inorder to generate charts with angular you could use some libraries out of which ng2-charts is a popular one.

You need to import the **`ChartsModule`**  in your **`NgModule`**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
```

and your **`Component.html`**

```
<div id="chart-container">
    <canvas #myCanvas id="canvas" baseChart [chartType]="chartType" [datasets]="chartData" [labels]="chartLabels" [colors]="chartColors" [options]="chartOptions"></canvas>
</div>
```

and **`Component.ts`**

```
this.chartData = [{
      data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
      label: 'Anthracnose',
      fill: false
    }];
    this.chartLabels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'];
    this.chartColors = [{
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    }];
    this.chartOptions = {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 1
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };
```

**[`DEMO ON STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart-911vkz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**